# ios progress bar in uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiprogressbar

I am new to ios how to update a progress bar in uitableview. generally I have a button, when I click a button in a particular cell I need to show progress bar in that cell only please help me and thanks in advance

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Categorycell";

    Categorycell *cell = (Categorycell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Categorycell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    [tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Categorycell";

    Categorycell *cell = (Categorycell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Categorycell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    [tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    NSLog(@"Index : %d",indexPath.row);
    NSString *str_filepath=[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.cell_img.image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:str_filepath];

    cell.title.text=[arr_book objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.sub_title.text=[arr_gen objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *str_rating=[arr_rating objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    int val_rating=[str_rating integerValue];

   // cell.cell_btn.hidden=YES;

    cell.cell_btn.tag       = indexPath.row*10+1;

    [cell.cell_btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    cell.cell_ReadBtn.tag       =indexPath.row*10+1;
    [cell.cell_ReadBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnRead:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    cell.cell_Progress.tag= indexPath.row*10+1;

    if(!bIspress)
    {
    cell.cell_Progress.hidden=YES;
    }
    NSString *comicbook_id = [arr_comic_id objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"book_%@.pdf",comicbook_id];
    NSLog(@"Book Name : %@",filePath);
    if(![appDelegate check_Book_available:filePath])
    {
        NSLog(@"Book Name Not : %@",filePath);
    cell.cell_ReadBtn.hidden=YES;
        cell.cell_btn.hidden= NO;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.cell_btn.hidden=YES;
        cell.cell_ReadBtn.hidden=NO;

    }
    cell.tag=indexPath.row*10+1;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: explain what you want to achieve i mean how the progress happen on cell click

Comment: i just need to show when i click the button in tablecell. i need to show progreess bar of those cell.i mean actually i hide progress bar after clicking button i need to show progressbar that's it please help me

Comment: so u mean you are able to hide it but not able to show, add some screenshots

Comment: actually i have a button and progress bar in coustom table cell when i add coustom table cell in table view , should visible only button from coustom table cell in table view after clicking the button it should hide the button and display progress bar...thanks for ur reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void) btnDown:(id)sender {
   UIButton* cellButton = (UIButton*)sender;
   NSIndexPath* selectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:cellButton.tag inSection:0];
   UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];

   for (id subView in cell.containView) {
      if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIProgressView class]) {
        UIProgressView * cellProgressView = (UIProgressView*)subView;
        cellProgressView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10, 50,50); setYourFrame;
        [cellProgressView setHidden:NO];
      }
   }
}
```

I hope this view do